# Oracle 11g Package fails sending a file trough ssh

Tags: linux, oracle, ssh, oracle11g, scp

I have a package on Oracle 11 that send a file trough ssh from an oracle folder to another destination (another machine or another user on the same machine).

The package send the file like this:

```
host_command(p_command => 'cd /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/oraclefolder;/usr/bin/scp -p txt.zip anotheruser@127.0.0.1:/home/anotheruser/userfolder');
```

But I am getiting this error:

```
"Host key verification failed.
 Mensaje : ORA-0000: normal, successful completion"
```

When I tried the same command on SQL Developer, it doesn't give any error but it doesn't work (the file is NOT sent):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000
BEGIN
host_command(p_command => 'cd /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1/oraclefolder;/usr/bin/scp -p txt.zip anotheruser@127.0.0.1:/home/anotheruser/userfolder');
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

When I try the same command on the linux machine (oracle user) also works (the file is sent as well):

```
[oracle@machine oraclefolder]$ /usr/bin/scp -p txt.zip anotheruser@127.0.0.1:/home/anotheruser/userfolder
txt.zip                                                            100%  166     0.2KB/s   00:00
[oracle@machine oraclefolder]$
```

I tried sending the file to a remote server and occur the same, the package fails but the command line works.
¿Why the package fails sending the file?

UPDATE: The same package works on another machine. The database was cloned and this clone was installed on another machine. This other machine could have another configuration but I am not sure where to look.

UPDATE: I know what is the issue but I don't know how to solve it. When I run the package trough SQL Developer or  TOAD, the files are being zipped and sent by user "grid", but when the package is run by itself (run by a job/schedule/program) the files are being zipped and sent by user oracle.
¿Who control what user create, zip, or send files?
¿How can I change this?

Comment: did you look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25021416/calling-shell-script-from-pl-sql-but-shell-gets-executed-as-grid-user-not-orac